# ¿Cómo utilizar Google Speech to text con Java y Netbeans? Problemas con las credenciales

Tags: java, google-api

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicación Web que pueda transcribir archivos de audio a archivos de texto. Para lo cuál quiero hacer uso de la API de Google Speech to Text. Para ver como funciona, antes de añadir esta función en la aplicación Web, realicé la guía rápida que viene en el siguiente enlace:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
com.google.auth.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials runningOnComputeEngine
INFORMACIÓN: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute 
Engine.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:132)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:115)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:88)
at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:59)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:140)
at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.stub.GrpcSpeechStub.create(GrpcSpeechStub.java:94)
at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.stub.SpeechStubSettings.createStub(SpeechStubSettings.java:126)
at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.<init>(SpeechClient.java:144)
at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:126)
at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.create(SpeechClient.java:118)
at com.example.speech.QuickstartSample.main(QuickstartSample.java:105)
BUILD FAILURE
```

Ya revisé el enlace al que me envía (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials). Seguí esa guía y añadí el siguiente código viene ahí para especificar explícitamente las credenciales

```
   static void authExplicit(String jsonPath) throws IOException {
  // You can specify a credential file by providing a path to GoogleCredentials.
 // Otherwise credentials are read from the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
 GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Windows/System32/key.json"))
    .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
 Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

 System.out.println("Buckets:");
 Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
 for (Bucket bucket : buckets.iterateAll()) {
   System.out.println(bucket.toString());
 }
}
```

Pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error. No tengo ni idea de cómo pasarle las credenciales para poder hacer uso de esta API,les agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publicando el error en otros foros, lograron ayudarme a encontrar la solución a este problema.

Para resolver este error hay que crear una nueva variable de usuario en el sistema (Equipo > Propiedades > Configuración avanzada del Sistema > Variables de entorno > Variables de usuario (Nueva)). El nombre de la variable es "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" y su valor será la ruta al archivo json que contiene sus credenciales.

Reinician Netbeans y con eso funcionará desde el IDE.

Les dejo mi código funcionando, el cual es el que viene el Quickstart de Google Cloud (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-java):

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionAudio;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeResponse;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionAlternative;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionResult;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;


public class QuickstartSample {
/**
 * Demonstrates using the Speech API to transcribe an audio file.
 */
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    // Instantiates a client
    try (SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create()) {

   // The path to the audio file to transcribe
   String fileName = [RUTA CON EL ARCHIVO A TRANSCRIBIR]

  // Reads the audio file into memory
  Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
  byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
  ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

  // Builds the sync recognize request
  RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
      .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
      //.setSampleRateHertz(16000)
      .setLanguageCode("es-MX")
      .build();
  RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
      .setContent(audioBytes)
      .build();

  // Performs speech recognition on the audio file
  RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.recognize(config, audio);
  List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

  for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
    // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
    // first (most likely) one here.
    SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
    System.out.printf("Transcripción: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Gracias por completar tu pregunta. :))